# trouble with array push in php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a problem with array push.I cant get the all data from the array array.I want to get like this format.

```
[["username","average"],["aa",2.34],["bb",6.7],["hh",9.8]]
```

here is my code

```
while($acc_rs = mysql_fetch_array($acc_qry))
{
  $acc_cnt    = $acc_rs['Total_login'];
  $time_stamp = $acc_rs['last_logged'];
  $avg_login  = $acc_rs['avg'];
  $name       = $acc_rs['name']; 
  $ji         = array();
  $sal        = array("username","average");
  $kk         = array($name,$avg_login);
  array_push($ji,$sal,$kk);
}
array_push($da,$new,$average);
```

Comment: That is pretty much json what you want. Try the answer provided below. Arrays and json are not the same thing. Also, if possible, stop using mysql, it is deprecated and can now be a potential threat as all support has ben dropped. Consider moving to PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array(array('username', 'average'));
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($acc_qry)) {
    $result[] = array($row['name'], $row['avg']);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```